# Android SMSManager Generic Failure

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm trying to send an SMS with the `android.telephony.SMSManager`.
When i send a SMS to someone around the country, it works. When i try so send an SMS to California for example, it doesnt work anymore.

Also, When i try to send a SMS to California, it returns a `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE` with errorcode 28.

Anyone knows what might be the issue?

Code used:

```
SmsManager sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault(); 
sms.sendTextMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.destination_address),    
null, getResources().getString(R.string.forward), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

I also added the `SEND_SMS` permission in the manifest file.

Thanks in advance.

Wouter.

Comment: Are you trying to send SMSes in a bulk ?

Comment: No not really, i already found the solution. Looks like i just had to add a +1 to the number since i want to send a message from Europe to US -_-.

Comment: You tried out the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending the country code:

```
 SmsManager sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault(); 
 sms.sendTextMessage("001" + getResources().getString(R.string.destination_address), null, getResources().getString(R.string.forward), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Answer (score 2):

Already found the solution !
Looks like i had to add +1 to the Destination phone numer since i want to send a SMS from Europe to US.